# Problem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a bounded region and $f\in H(G)\cap C(\bar{G})$ [$H$ means analyticity and $C$ means continuity]. If $|f(z)|$ is constant on the boundary of $G$. prove either $f(z)$ has a zero in $G$ or $f$ is constant. I am not quite sure, but I think I have to use maximum principle... but yet don't know how to do that. Thank you very much.

One more problem

If $f\in C(\Bbb C)\cap H(\Bbb C\backslash \delta B_1(0))$ then $f\in H(\Bbb C)$ [C means continuous, $\Bbb C$ means complex plane, H means analytic and $\delta$ means boundary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is as above. Then by the maximum modulus principle, $|f|$ occurs on the boundary of $G$. If $f(z)\neq 0$, $\forall z\in G$, consider $g:=\frac{1}{f}$ over $G$. Then by the maximum modulus principle $|g|$ occurs on the boundary of $G$. Thus $|g|=|\frac{1}{f}|=\frac{1}{|f|}$ occurs on the boundary of $G$. But this will happen only when $|f|$ is smallest. Therefore, $|f|$ obtains it's minimum on the boundary of $G$. Since $|f|$ is constant on the boundary, $\min|f|=\max|f|$ and therefore $f$ is constant.

Therefore, either $f(z)=0$ for some $z$, or $f$ is constant.

Comment: Can you help me with the second problem

Comment: @Raven I would recommend making another post with the new question and what you have tried so far! That way if other's search for something similar, both questions will be available upon searching.